# Getting the selected View from ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, onclicklistener

I am using a `CursorAdapter` to handle my `ListActivity`:

```
public class Mclass extends ListActivity{
...
TheAdapter mAdapter;
public static HashMap<Long, Boolean> shown = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();
...

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
         Boolean tmp = shown.get(id); 
        if (tmp == null) { // if null we don't have this key in the hashmap so we added with the value true
            shown.put(id, true);
        } else {
            shown.put(id, !tmp.booleanValue()); // if the value exists in the map then inverse it's value
        }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }

}
```

and my adapter class that extends `CursorAdapter` and overrides `bindView`:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    String listText= cursor
            .getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataHandler.MY_TEXT));

long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataHandler.ROW_ID)); 
    if (Mclass.shown.get(id) != null) {
        TextView m_text = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.my_text);
        if (m_text != null) {
            m_text.setVisibility(Mclass.shown.get(id)? View.VISIBLE:
                     View.GONE);

            if (m_text.isShown())
                m_text.setText("STRING");
   }
}
```

My list item layout is defined in a xml file `list_item.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#DDDDDD"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingRight="1dip"
        android:paddingTop="1dip"
</LinearLayout>

/*
 *I want to toggle this text view's visibility
 */
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"//VISIBILITY defined here
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingLeft="4dip"
    android:paddingRight="4dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

How can I toggle the visibility of the `TextView` in my layout within `onListItemClick`?
I've tried:

```
TextView mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_text);
mTextView.setVisibility(mTextView.isShown()? View.GONE: View.VISIBLE);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

but it seems to be choosing which list items to toggle at random, regardless of the one I click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to store the id's of the rows you'll hide. You could make a field in your activity to store those ids:

```
HashMap<Long, Boolean> positionHide = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();
```

where the key is the long id of the row and the boolean object represents the status of the `TextView`(false- it is gone, true it is visible). In the `onListItemClick()` add the ids of the clicked rows to that field:

```
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
         Boolean tmp = positionHide.get(id); 
        if (tmp == null) { // if null we don't have this key in the hashmap so we added with the value true
            status.put(id, true);
        } else {
            status.put(id, !tmp.booleanValue()); // if the value exists in the map then inverse it's value
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

also modify the `bindView()` method:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    String listText = cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataHandler.MY_TEXT));
    long pos = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataHandler.ID)); // DataHandler.ID will point to the column _id
TextView m_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_text);

    if(status.get(pos) == null) {
//id is not yet in the hashmap so the value is 
//by default false, the TextView is invisible
    m_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    } else {
        // we have the value in the
        // Hashmap so see what it is and set the
    // textview visibility from this value

        if (tmp.booleanValue()) {
          m_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             } else {
                 m_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   }
          }
    if (m_text != null)
     m_text.setText(listText);  

}
```

For this to work you'll need to have in your database the column `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`(and also added to the query).

Comment: Great! I see where you're going with this. But in order to toggle, wouldn't I have to remove AND add my id's from `ArrayList<Long> positionHide` then do another check in `bindView`?

Comment: @ababzy Sorry when i first read your question I only saw "hide the `TextView`". See my updated answer.

Comment: @ababzy I forgot, you must call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` on `listItemClick()` to notify the `ListView` that something was updated.

Comment: It was a nice try, but it did not do the trick. I am still seeing random list items's `TextView`s being set to `VISIBLE` and the text does not even show up this time. I have updated my question with your code implemented if you wan to take a look.

Comment: @ababzy That happens when you don't implement correctly the `bindView()` method. Here is a sample activity where i tested my response http://pastebin.com/cvChb8PB . Run it and see how to  correctly implement the adapter and `getview()`.

Comment: You're right, I was missing a key piece of logic. When `bindView` is called for a new row, it is important to force the row's `TextView` to `View.GONE` because it is being reused. Thank you, your code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is that views are reused in list view. This meens that even if you have a list consisting of 100 items, there will be only 10 or so view instances (depending on how much can be fitted on the screen). If you can seen the method bindView takes a view to reuse as parameter.

What you have done, is taken a view that displays for example the 23rd item in the list, and hide the text box. When the 23rd item is scrolled out of the screen, it's view gets reused, but only the values are replaced with the 33rd item's data, the visiblity and other parameters you set for the View you're reusing remains the same.

What you should do is add a status boolean to all list items, and in the adapter's bindView toggle the text boxes visibility according to the currently wanted state of the item.

The other important thing to see is that when you click on the item, the bindView method is not called. So you should also toggle the visibility in the onClick method, to make the change instantious. If you miss this, the view's apparance will change only after the item is scrolled out and scrolled in again - that's when the bindView checks for the visibility boolean.

It would be more elegent to notify the DataSetObservers of the change in the "data", and let the ListView call the bindView for all visible items, but its also more resource consuming.

```
HashMap<Long, Boolean> positionHide = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
         Boolean tmp = positionHide.get(id); 
        if (tmp == null) { // if null we don't have this key in the hashmap so we added with the value true
            positionHide.put(id, true);
            tmp = true;
        } else {
                        tmp = !tmp.booleanValue();
            positionHide.put(id, !tmp.booleanValue()); // if the value exists in the map then inverse it's value
        }
        // You should also hide the text view, because bindView will not be called until the list item is scrolled out and in again
                TextView m_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_text);
        if (m_text != null) {
              if(tmp) {
                            // We should hide the text view
                            m_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  } else {
                        // We should display the text view
                            m_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  }
        } 
    }


@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    String listText = cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataHandler.MY_TEXT));
            TextView m_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_text);
    if (m_text != null) {
          m_text.setText(listText);
          long pos = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataHandler.ID)); // DataHandler.ID will point to the column _id
          if((positionHide.get(pos) != null)&&(positionHide.get(pos))) {
                        // We should hide the text view
                        m_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              } else {
                    // We should display the text view
                        m_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              }
            }
}
```

For this to work you'll need to have in your database the column `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`(and also added to the query).

Comment: I see! This explains why it seems to be setting the visibility status for random items when I select an item. I realize `getView` would work, but it would also defeat the purpose of using a `CursorAdapter`.

Comment: You're right, don't use a custom array type adapter for this, stick with CursorAdapter, and rely on slukian's answer, it's basically the same thing, but with a cursor and the bindView method. As he wrote, in stead of an array, use a hash map to associate the "Display Text View" state to the id of the current item, and check this hashmap for each new item. I'll edit the code for you.

Comment: Edit is under peer review, I add the edited code to my answer. The important thing is to change the visiblity in the on click too, as the flag that you set in the HashMap will only take effect after your item is scrolled out, and scrolled back again - that's when bind view is called.
Another solution would be to notify dataset listeners about the change, when an item is clicked. That is a bit cleaner MWC design, but using the listener to hide items is more economic form a coding and also from a processing point of view (when dataset listeners notified, bindView will be called 4all items.)

Answer (score 1):

Well you shouldn't use `ListView` for any active View, try using TableLayout or LinearLayout instead.
Look at [this blog](http://android347.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/android-development-listview-vs-tablelayout-with-checkboxes/) post for more details on this, however it's for CheckBoxes,but holds true for any active View.

Comment: Incorrect, because of the way listview optimizes views for large number of items, its not always advisable to use Table or Linear layout for large number of items

Comment: @the100rabh Exactly, and I've added the warning in the blog post already. However if the rows are less, there're  not a very significant drop in performance.