# CheckedTextViews will randomly appear checked in a list if I click one further up the list

Tags: android, android-listview, checkedtextview

Ok, so this has been somewhat addressed alot on this site, however I do not believe the exact problem with what my code uses. I am filling a listView with CheckedTextViews which works completely. However when I click on an item it gets checked but when I scroll up and down random rows are also checked. I realize it must have something to do with how the ListView keeps track of the items. I am running into some errors at the moment. I attempted to fill a hashmap with the list of the rows so I can keep track which one is set to true and which are false. However I am not positive where to implement the map and try to fill it.

Here is my OnCreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewmenu);

    //Get table name of menu clicked. 
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    tableName = extras.getString("table");

    // map each contact's name to a TextView in the ListView layout
    String[] from = new String[] { "name" };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.toppingCheckedTextView };

    for(int i=0; i< from.length; i++){
        map.put(i, false);
    }

    contactAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            ViewToppingListing.this, R.layout.toppings_list_item, null, from, to);
    setListAdapter(contactAdapter); // set contactView's adapter
 }
```

I attempt to place the map in the onCreate to fill it however it complains about a nullpointer.

Here is where I tried using the OnListItemClick method

```
 @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){      
    final int index = arg2 - arg0.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View v = arg0.getChildAt(index);
    CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toppingCheckedTextView);

    if((Boolean)map.get(index) == true){
        ctv.setChecked(true);
        ctv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else{
        ctv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }   

}
```

I have read alot on this, and it seems that alot of solutions involves using getView(), however I don't know if that applies to my situation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all do you need a `SimpleCursorAdapter`? You set the adapter with a `null` cursor:

```
contactAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            ViewToppingListing.this, R.layout.toppings_list_item, null, from, to); // the third parameter is the cursor and you set it to null!
```

The behavior you see it's because of the `ListView` is recycling views and yes you'll have to implement your own adapter and override `bindView()`. The code bellow is based on another answer to a similar question maybe you'll want to look at it( [Getting the selected View from ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546386/getting-the-selected-view-from-listview/9546543#9546543) ). Here is an example:

```
public class TestCursorAdapter extends ListActivity {

    MySimpleAdapter adapter;
    private HashMap<Long, Boolean> positionHide = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String[] columns = new String[] { "_id", "name" };
        MatrixCursor mc = new MatrixCursor(columns); // cursor for testing
        for (int i = 1; i < 35; i++) {
            long id = i;
            mc.addRow(new Object[] { id, "Name" + i });
        }
        String[] from = new String[] { "name" };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.checked_text };
        adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(this,
                R.layout.adapter_mysimpleadapter_row, mc, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

        public MySimpleAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
                String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
            CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.checked_text);
            long pos = cursor.getLong(0); // the id from the cursor
            if (positionHide.get(pos) == null) {
                ctv.setChecked(false);
                // we don't have this id in the hashmap so the value is by
                // default false, the TextView is GONE
            } else {
                // we have the value in the Hashmap so see what it is and set
                // the textview visibility from this value
                Boolean tmp = positionHide.get(pos);
                if (tmp.booleanValue()) {
                    ctv.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    ctv.setChecked(false);
                }
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Boolean tmp = positionHide.get(id);
        if (tmp == null) {
            // if null we don't have this key in the hashmap so
            // we add it with the value true
            positionHide.put(id, true);
        } else {
            positionHide.put(id, !tmp.booleanValue());
            // if the value exists in the map then inverse it's value
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // notify the adapter that something has
                                        // changed
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! that works! And I started using the SimpleCursor because I saw it in a tutorial. If I am calling a cursor in the background in an AsyncTask, should I still not use a cursor?

Comment: @James.Bradley It doesn't matter where you're calling it, what is important is that if your data comes from a database or a source that returns a `Cursor` then you should use a `Cursor` related adapter and if the data is something like a list then you should use a simple adapter (like `ArrayAdapter`). I just saw that you use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` that expects a `Cursor` with data but you pass `null`.